# If I provide info to an immigration officer, does he enter it into a database?

Tags: air-travel, customs-and-immigration, international-travel, airports

I.e. length of stay and itinerary, is this only for the officer's personal info or is he actually entering this information?

Comment: Each country, or even each border post may have its own practice. Which country are you insterested in? In general, any thing that's systematially written down/recorded on computer (landing cards, kiosk declarations, officer's notes etc.) is archived. Officers cannot generally use your provided information for "personal" use; and in many countries, they could be legally required to enter the informaton into database due to privacy and freedom of information issues.

Comment: @zhantongz I am *mainly* interested in Germany.

Comment: The question is a little too broad to be useful but it does suggest you have a more specific concern. Are you planning to lie about the intended length of stay to avoid scrutiny of your purpose or finances or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As other as provided, this varies a lot.

In some situations, the officer is actually checking your answers against data they already have, whether it's from a visa application, an ESTA/ETA/eVisitor/etc. application, a landing card, your airline PNR (they may have access to your return flight).

That's why they sometime ask questions which may seem completely stupid to you because it's written on the passport or other documentation they have right before their eyes: they're checking if your story is consistent. Believe it or not, they can catch quite a few people like that: a people smuggler filled in the applications or provided fake IDs for the "visitor", but the "visitor" did not (correctly) learn the details of what they are supposed to have said/planning to do or even who they are supposed to be.

In other cases, it's just questions that will help them gauge whether they should press further or send you on you way. Some people just don't know/understand the rules, and will either bluntly reply things like "oh I'm here to settle down with by girlfriend/boyfriend" or "I'm planning to stay for a year and find work here and there to support myself and so on" (instant rejection) or reply something like "I'm planning to stay 3 months" which will lead to further questions on what the visitor is planning to do, how they are going to support themselves for that long, and so on.

I expect that in the majority of "easy" cases (though this very probably varies a lot from country to country), where the answers are consistent with the info they already have and nothing raises any flags, they will not make a note of any of the answers, or only minimal information.

However, as soon as there's anything suspicious (long or repeated stays, inconsistencies, adverse history, etc.), the probability they will make a note of everything you say increases significantly, if only to see if in further questioning (including secondary inspection by other officers) the story doesn't change even further.

Note that in some countries, immigration officers will also make notes on your customs form that are intended for the customs officers. As the IO has more information at hand, they can "warn" the customs officers of any suspicions they may have.

Note that in some countries, you may actually be recorded (audio and/or video) during part or all of your interactions.

In any case, you should consider that they will record and archive everything you tell them and will be able to compare your statements to your actions or subsequent statements. The very simple rule is to **never** lie to an immigration or customs officer. Do not voluntarily provide information they did not ask for, but do **not** lie.

Comment: This answer elegantly refers to questions which are asked not to see what you say (at least, not primarily) but to see how you say it.  Some have said that 90% of human-to-human communication is not vocalised; border officials, who are often highly-trained to pick up on this extra information, sometimes ask questions designed to elicit it.

Comment: What is this answer based on? It seems to overstate how much information is recorded *in databases*.

Answer (score 1):

> If I provide info to an immigration officer, does he enter it into a database?

Yes in some case, no in others: there a millions of combinations of your citizenship(s), country of origin, country of entrance, time of day, type of border crossing, equipment available, mood & attitude of the immigration office, many more.